# Array formula to extract N non blank cell in Row 1-16

Tags: google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-forms

I have a google form where team coaches input which players played on a given day.

They also input if they were Man of the Match, Yellow/Red Cards Received, and how many Goals they scored.

[image: Google Form Tick Box Grid]

When the form is submitted there are blank Columns where players did not play.
There are 11 age groups and 4 teams within each age group, roughly 400 players, therefore 400 columns!

This is team WHITES.

[image]

In Columns to the right (after the last player of the last team) i need to register only the players that played and omit the non playing players.

I have the following code but it's not extracting the correct data.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
IF(ISBLANK($A1:$A),"",
IF(ROW($A1:$A)=ROW($A$1),"Player "&COLUMN(A1),


QUERY(TRANSPOSE(M2:JM),"Select Col1 where Col1 is not null limit 1",0))))
```

As it is automating a Google Form the first three lines of the formula can be ignored. Its from ***QUERY(*** which is the problem.

The formula in JN1 is then copied right for 16 Players

[image]

**Dave** should be **Player 3 with 1 Goal** and **FRED** should be **Player 4 with 2 Goals** and the rest should be blank.

Is Query/Transpose the correct way extract this data or something else?